# Vue 2.1 calling method in beforeCreate hook is not working

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, hook, vue.js, lifecycle

I am making an async call to some local `json` data before my component is created. So this code actually works fine:

```
  beforeCreate : function() {
    var self = this;
      fetch('/assets/data/radfaces.json')
        .then(function(response) { return response.json()
        .then( function(data) { self.users = data; } );
      })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

Now I just want to refactor and move this to a separate method:

```
  beforeCreate : function() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchUsers: function() {
      var self = this;
      fetch('/assets/data/radfaces.json')
        .then(function(response) { return response.json()
        .then( function(data) { self.users = data; } );
      })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

And now everything stops working. I get an error: `app.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: this.fetchUsers is not a function(…)`

Why can't I access the `fetchUsers` method in the `beforeCreate` hook? What is the work around?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's because `methods` hasn't been initialized yet. The easiest way around this it to use the `created` hook instead:

```
  created : function() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchUsers: function() {
      var self = this;
      fetch('/assets/data/radfaces.json')
        .then(function(response) { return response.json()
        .then( function(data) { self.users = data; } );
      })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know where in the documentation I can read about this?

Comment: Yes, you can find out more here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks